# Python: create a decimal number out of entries from a text file

Tags: python, file, parsing, text, binary

I have a text file containing entries similar to the following example:

```
# 8 rows of header
---------------------------------------------
123 ABC12345 A some more variable length text
456 DEF12345 A some more variable length text
789 GHI12345 B some more variable length text
987 JKL12345 A some more variable length text
654 MNO12345 B some more variable length text
321 PQR12345 B some more variable length text
etc...
```

What I would like to achieve is:

1. Convert the As into 1s, the Bs into 0s in order to have a binary number
   For the example above this would be 110100 (i.e. AABABB)
2. Convert this binary number into a decimal number
   For the example above this would then be 52
3. Map this decimal number to a text string
   (i.e. 52 = "Case 1" or 53 = "Case 2" etc.) and
4. Print this on the stdout

I have a little bit of Python experience but the problem above is way beyond my capabilities. Therefore any help from the community would be appreciated.
Many thanks in advance,
Hib

Comment: You need to finish defining the problem before you can find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
from itertools import islice

binary_map = dict(zip("AB", "10"))  # Equivalent to {"A": "1", "B": "0"}
string_map = {52: "Case 1", 53: "Case 2"}

with open("my_text_file") as f:
    binary_str = "".join(binary_map[x.split()[2]] for x in islice(f, 9, None))

binary_value = int(binary_string, 2)
print string_map[binary_value]
```

I'll break down the indented code line for you and explain it.

- The `join` method of an empty string will concatenate the strings given in the argument, so `"".join(["A", "B", "C"])` is equal to `"ABC"`.
- We pass this method a so-called [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), `X for Y in Z`. It has the same syntax as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), except the square brackets are omitted.
- The [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function returns an iterator that silently skips the first 9 lines of the file object `f`, so it yields lines starting with the 10th.
- The `split` method of `str` with no arguments will split on any sequence of whitespace characters (space, tab (`"\t"`), linefeed (`"\n"`) and carriage return (`"\r"`)) and return a list. So for example, `"  a \t b\n\t c\n".split()` is equal to `['a', 'b', 'c']`. We're interested in the third column, `x.split()[2]`, which is either `"A"` or `"B"`.
- Looking up this value in the `binary_map` dictionary will give us either `"1"` or `"0"` instead.

Comment: I would use `itertools.islice` to skip the first 8 lines.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you and especially for the code explanation. This was extremely helpful. I managed to get the script running in the end and to produce the output I needed.

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers (assuming Python 2):

Translating a string:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans("AB","10")
>>> translated = "AABABB".translate(table)
>>> translated
'110100'
```

Converting to base 10:

```
>>> int(translated, 2)
52
```

No idea how you would map that to those arbitrary strings - more information needed.

Printing to `stdout` - really? Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

a.txt:

```
# 8 rows of header







123 ABC12345 A some more variable length text
456 DEF12345 A some more variable length text
789 GHI12345 B some more variable length text
987 JKL12345 A some more variable length text
654 MNO12345 B some more variable length text
321 PQR12345 B some more variable length text
```

you can try this:

```
>>> int(''.join([line.split(' ')[2] for line in open('a.txt', 'r').readlines()[8:]]).replace('A', '1').replace('B', '0'), 2)
>>> 52
```

As for mapping the int to a string, not sure what you mean.

```
>>> value = {int(''.join([line.split(' ')[2] for line in open('a.txt', 'r').readlines()[8:]]).replace('A', '1').replace('B', '0'), 2): 'case 52'}  
>>> value[52]
'case 52'
>>>
```

Comment: Fitting everything on one line is not the primary goal you should be aiming for :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker lol yes, I guess I do it out of habit and because it tends to be popular, but this are very poor excuses, I may just be infatuated with the fact that python allows me to do such a thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used `re` module in order to check the format of the lines to be accepted:

```
>>> def map_file_to_string(string):
    values = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        if re.match(r'\d{3} \w{3}\d{5} [AB] .*', line):
            values.append(1 if line[13] == 'A' else 0)
    return dict_map[int(''.join(map(str, values)), 2)]

>>> dict_map = {52: 'Case 1', 53: 'Case 2'}
>>> s1 = """# 8 rows of header
---------------------------------------------
123 ABC12345 A some more variable length text
456 DEF12345 A some more variable length text
789 GHI12345 B some more variable length text
987 JKL12345 A some more variable length text
654 MNO12345 B some more variable length text
321 PQR12345 B some more variable length text
etc.."""
>>> map_file_to_string(s1)
'Case 1'
>>>
```